# get download url from returned parameter by mega.nz API [PHP]

Tags: php, api, mega-api

I use [this simple PHP code](https://github.com/paulomanrique/MySQLBackupMegaCoNZ/blob/master/MySQLBackupMegaCoNZ.php) for uploading a file to mega.nz cloud, and the code works correctly.

the code return an array like this:

```
h => GxsyWLTK
t => 0
a => KxaM1xBhlW8oAc1zECKfnk7uSulGtHy0FKagNNF2iFo
k => 6ffMqPn8b0Y:fsN980rUUZhmDNBnDZM7PjM2S5rQe-7oTjLVbssQ2F4
p => jwsyAbxY
ts => 1422434349
u => 6ffMqPn8b0Y
s => 30751
```

but i want to know: how i can get **download link** of the uploaded file that is like this link?
https://mega.nz/#!SttF0BiC!BXQIrgxB9Q5qWmccdjMnsISUCyRV4Hr6f-v5RjQxB_w

Comment: You're using a lot of links in your question, it would help a lot if you could trim this down to a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then include the code any relevant information in the body of your question. Links can decay and your question won't make any sense without them.

Comment: thanks @Aiken. I remove the links and remain only 1 link that show the php code that i use.

Comment: @علیرضا: Please include your code in the question.  Do not link to it.

Comment: @علیرضاIm having the same, did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The result contains, for each node, the the following informations:

```
h: The ID of the node ; --> <ID-NODE>
p: The ID of the parent node (directory) ;
u: The owner of the node ;
t: The type of the node:
  0: File
  1: Directory
  2: Special node: Root (“Cloud Drive”)
  3: Special node: Inbox
  4: Special node: Trash Bin
a: The attributes of the node. Currently only contains its name.
k: The key of the node; --> <KEY-NODE>
s: The size of the node ;
ts: The time of the last modification of the node
```

General Mega download link:

```
https://mega.nz/#! <ID-NODE> ! <KEY-NODE>
```

Example (with your data):

```
https://mega.nz/#!GxsyWLTK!6ffMqPn8b0Y:fsN980rUUZhmDNBnDZM7PjM2S5rQe-7oTjLVbssQ2F4
```

Hope this helps.